# Best practice: Where should I write functions (not methods) in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

This is maybe not a fundamental question, but as curious as I am, I'm asking this myself for a long time.

A part of Django code is functions and is not directly related to Django models.
Let's take for example this function :

```
def make_random_raw_password(length=8):
    # Do some stuff and return a 8 char randomised string
```

Technically, this function is not related to the User class, but functionally, it is!

Where would you write this function?
From my beginner point of view, I can see at least 2 options:

1. I create a `myutils.py` file which contains all these kind of functions then I import `myutils.py` in files like `models.py` / `view.py` to use these functions.
2. I move this function as a classmethod in my UserProxy class (since I can not directly modify the User class methods in Django) which gives me something close to:

-

```
class UserProxy(User):
    class Meta(object):
        proxy = True

    @classmethod
    def make_random_raw_password(cls, length=8):
        # Do some stuff...
```

Which one would you use? Could you explain why? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tangential note: you _can_ [subclass the django.contrib.auth.models.User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) and use your custom User model for authentication. Otherwise your question seems off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I actually already do this, but I have several models that inherits from the `User` class (`BusinessUserProfile` and `ClientUserProfile`). To stay DRY, I can't write methods in all xxxUserProfile methods.

Comment: Since this method is used in models I usually put it in models.py. And methods that are not used in models I put in utils.py in the app.